# How can I modify a language definition file for Atom and have it live-update?

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor, cson

I'm trying to tweak the language definition file for Python, and while it's easy enough to clone and fork the `atom/language-python` repo, I'm not quite sure how give my edited CSON grammar definition file to Atom to use. Under Windows, the Atom install looks all wrapped up into packages and archives, I can't just hack on a single file.

Advertised as being so "hackable", how can I hack in my changes to a language highlighter to get them to show up? Do I need to convert the CSON to a JSON?